# use recompose in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, recompose

I have a component which is developed using react and redux. Now that i want to use recompose, I did not understand the organized way to use it with the redux. By organized way, I mean to say before i used to have two function like `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and they are wrapped in `connect HOC` which makes code look more readable and clean in my opinion. My question is how do i do the same like the way i was doing for the redux part ? I could not find when searching for that way so I am not sure if there is a way or not if it is can anyone help me by sharing it, please?

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loginData: state.loginData,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  login: user => dispatch(login(user)),
});

class Login extends React.Component<{ login: Function }> {
  state = {
    error: false,
    user: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, [name]: value } });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state.user);
  };

  renderError() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return (
        <ErrorMessage>
          The following email is not associated with us. Please create an
          account to use our service
        </ErrorMessage>
      );
    }
    return <div />;
  }
  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
      <WhitePart>
        <UpperPart>
          <TitleContainer>
            <TitleText>Login</TitleText>
          </TitleContainer>
          {this.renderError()}
          <Form>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <StyledField
                label="Email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="text"
                value={user.email}
                placeholder="Email"
                className="input-field"
                component={GTextField}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: '20px',
                }}
                required
                fullWidth
              />
              <StyledField
                label="Password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                value={user.password}
                placeholder="Password"
                className="input-field"
                component={GPasswordField}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
                fullWidth
              />
              <ButtonContainer>
                <PrimaryButton
                  type="submit"
                  style={{
                    textTransform: 'none',
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    fontWeight: 300,
                  }}
                >
                  Login
                </PrimaryButton>
              </ButtonContainer>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </UpperPart>
      </WhitePart>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Login);
```

for handleChange and handleSubmit i can do using withHandler and withState but for mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps i am not familiar.

Comment: Which part do you want to be organized?

Comment: mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in recmpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

```
export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  ),
  withStateHandlers,
  withHandler,
)(Login);
```

---

**Bonus!**

You don't need a separate `mapDispatchToProps` when using `recompose`.
We like to use Recompose's `withHandlers` for all handlers, including Redux dispatches.

It looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signUpUser, loginUser } from './someActionsFile';

const LandingScreen = props => (
  <ButtonContainer>
    <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={props.dispatchSignUpUser} />
    <Button title="Log In" onPress={props.dispatchLoginUser} />
    <Button title="Say Hi!!" onPress={props.sayHi} />
  </ButtonContainer>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   loginData: state.loginData,
});

const myHandlers = withHandlers({
  dispatchSignUpUser: ({ dispatch }) => () => {
    dispatch(signUpUser());
  },
  dispatchLoginUser: ({ dispatch }) => () => {
    dispatch(loginUser());
  },
  sayHi: () => () => {
    console.log('Hi!!');
  }
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps), // Once connect() is composed `dispatch` is prop.
  myHandlers
)(LandingScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus. I was not familiar on that.

Answer (score 3):

### for mapStateToProps:

You can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to move selector logic into another file, then share selectors across components.

### for mapDispatchToProps:

you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to move async logic into seperate files.

Comment: Sorry my question could not make you clear. I found the solution. it should be compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withState, withHandler). Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Great, This helps me too.